# Replacing ACL with Inheritance using PowerShell

Tags: powershell-3.0

I've done some research and still can't seem to find a way to replace the ACLs with the parent ACL like it was done with this one command using FILEACL:

```
FILEACL.exe c:\parent_folder\child_folder /INHERIT /REPLACE /SUB
```

I am aware of using the get-acl and set-acl cmdlets, and even using .NET, but maybe I am missing a certain .NET method for this.

I undersand I can do something like this, but it doesn't seem to do what I am hoping with replacing the ACLs of the parent_folder or any of its children:

```
$acl = get-acl "c:\parent_folder"
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($False, $True) # Turn on inheritence; 2nd paramter ignored if 1st is false
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
function Reset-FolderPermissionsRecursively {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$modelFolder,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$targetFolder
    )

    # Reset permissions for parent folder and remove explicit (non-inherited) permissions
    $modelFolderAcl = Get-Acl -path $modelFolder
    Write-Host "Setting permissions on $targetFolder to match $modelFolder"
    Set-Acl -path $targetFolder -aclObject $modelFolderAcl
    $acl = Get-Acl $targetFolder
    $aces = $acl.Access
    foreach ($ace in $aces) {
        if ($ace.IsInherited -eq $FALSE) {
            Write-Host "Removing $ace on $targetFolder"
            $acl.RemoveAccessRule($ace)
            Set-Acl $targetFolder $acl
        }
    }

    # Reset permissions for parent folder's children and remove explicit (non-inherited) permissions
    Get-ChildItem $targetFolder -recurse -attributes d | foreach {
        Write-Host "Setting permissions on" $_.fullName "to match $modelFolder"
        Set-Acl -path $_.fullName -aclObject $modelFolderAcl
        $acl = Get-Acl $_.FullName
        $aces = $acl.Access
        foreach ($ace in $aces) {
            if ($ace.IsInherited -eq $FALSE) {
                Write-Host "Removing $ace on" $_.fullName
                $acl.RemoveAccessRule($ace)
                Set-Acl $_.FullName $acl
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I struggled a lot regarding a similar issue today: Just wanting to reset a directory's ACLs to "inherited only". There are certain corner cases with RemoveAccessRule (as @Bangaio noted, I'd like to add: there's all kinds of funky behaviour if you got domain-migrated groups with sidHistory in them - you cannot remove them reliably from an ACL, the only way is building a completely new ACL).

I came up with this code:

```
$item = Get-Item "your-path" 
$acl = $item.GetAccessControl("Access")
$acl.SetAccessruleProtection($false,$true)
# enable inheritance first
$item.SetAccesscontrol($acl)
# create new empty ACL, effectively removing all inherited ACLs
$newacl = new-object System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity
$item.SetAccesscontrol($newacl)
```

This is basically the equivalent of

```
icacls $path /inheritance:e
icacls $path /reset
```

Rationale for using `GetAccessControl` and `SetAccessControl`: less permission issues. If I use `get-acl` and `set-acl` it complains about missing "SeSecurityPrivilege" permission (might by related to trying to set the owner or audit ACL entries), using `SetAccessControl` avoids that.

Answer (score 0):

Removing explicit (non-inherited) on a registry key (and its subkeys) didn't work for me because entries with `ALL APLICATION PACKAGES` (SID: `S-1-15-2-1`) would fail with the `RemoveAccessRule` method.
Instead, create a new ACL object and set that on the key.

Sample code:

```
$path = HKCU:\path\to\key
$aclNew = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.RegistrySecurity
# allow inheritance (it's the default, but added for clarity)
$aclNew.SetAccessRuleProtection($False,$False)
Set-Acl -Path $path -AclObject $aclNew
```

References:

https://github.com/osquery/osquery/issues/7165

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/e9b94c25-631b-4923-b318-b5a29704437b/file-and-folder-permission-problem-in-windows-10-v1809?forum=win10itprosecurity